# Failed to install flutter_launch.dart dependency

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I just added the flutter launch dependency to be able to open whatsapp from my application but it returns the following problem:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  project ':flutter_launch' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        33.1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the package bumped the Kotlin version to `1.3.40` in [this commit](https://github.com/thyagoluciano/flutter_launch_whatsapp/commit/d29f6359d339286519d682fb19dc4b48d3de0625).

Make sure you have the latest version lised in you `pubspec.yaml` file.

If that still does not work and you already ran `flutter clean`, try o depend directly on the Github repository adding the following to your `pubspec.yaml`file:

```
flutter_launch:
  git:
    url:https://github.com/thyagoluciano/flutter_launch_whatsapp.git
```